# How to find elements having a class not childrien of elements having this class

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This may sounds tricky. You will understand more easily with the data :

```
<div>
    <h1>
       <div class='nested ok selected'></div>
    </h1>
    <div class='ok selected'>
        <div class='ko selected'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='ok selected'></div>
</div>
```

I would like to select all the `selected` class not being a child of a `selected` element whatever be the depth of it. The result should match the `ok` elements. I struggle mostly because of the `nested` element, otherwise it would have been pretty straightforward.

Any clue ?

Thanks!

EDIT : I can't change the HTML and the `ok`, `nested` and `ko` selectors are just here as clarifications of my problem.

Comment: y not rewrite the html to suit your needs better

Comment: Is `ko selected` it typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".selected:not(:parent(.selected))")
```

Demo showing the number of elements returned: http://jsfiddle.net/3YU4B/

Comment: Didn't knew about the :parent selector, +1

Comment: @Darhazer I've found out about it just recently. It's really handy.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to grab all selected elements, than filter out the ones that are under another selected

```
$('.selected').filter(function(){
   return $(this).parents('.selected').size() == 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AQaQs/)

```
$(function(){
        $(".selected").each(function(){
           if($(this).parents(".selected").length==0)
           {
               console.log(this);
           }

        });
    });
```